# In my coding bootstrap works on a part of the page but not for the whole. Why this happens?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use bootstrapping to my whole project. But, the bootstrap works for the heading tag and not for the others. My codes are as follows.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12">         
            <form class="form-horizontal templatemo-create-account templatemo-container" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="" method="post">
            <div class="form-inner">
            <center><em><h2>New Cumulative Deposit Account</h2></em></center>
            <div id="cum_app_info">
            <center> <h3> Personal Information </h3></center>
                <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                <td> <label for="cumfirstapp" class="control-label">First Applicant</label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="first_app" id="first_app"  required class="form-control" value=""> </td>
                <td> <label for="cumfirstappid" class="control-label">Member Id</label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="first_cum_app_id" id="first_cum_app_id" required class="form-control" value=""> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td> <label for="cumsecondapp" class="control-label">Second Applicant</label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="second_app" id="second_app" class="form-control" value=""> </td>
                <td> <label for="cumsecondappid" class="control-label">Member Id</label> </td>
                <td> <input type="text" name="second_cum_app_id" id="second_cum_app_id" class="form-control" value=""> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><input type="submit" name="cum_app_next" class="btn btn-info" id="cum_app_next" value="Next" />
 </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                </div>
                </div>
                </form>
                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap? What is the full HTML for the page? Can you please try to reproduce this using something like [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co), [jsBin](http://jsbin.com), [CodePen](http://codepen.io) or the inbuilt snippet support on StackOverflow?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=cuHJT1uKwD

Comment: Did you forget to include the Bootstrap CSS? [It works here](http://jsfiddle.net/kqjcfkvk/).

Comment: No dude.. It works only for the heading tags here.. Anyway thank u dude.

Comment: its working here...may be the issue is not in the code you posted here may be something else is wrong in your implementation

Comment: Yeah, definitely working. See this [screenshot of it working just fine](http://i.imgur.com/En3J6Nl.png) in Chrome version 41.0.2272.118 m.

Comment: @Jegannath Any update on this? As you can see, it works fine for all of us, even in Firefox ([screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/5foqKLi.png)). Can you reproduce it in jsFiddle? If not, then this question should be closed, because there is something at play here we can't know and thus can't help you. Otherwise, you can update your question with more details so we have a shot at helping you.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some minor changes like replacing the "center" elements with .text-center classes but it was working fine for me.
http://jsfiddle.net/c6b2trmw/1/

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="form-horizontal templatemo-create-account templatemo-container" enctype="multipart/form-data" role="form" action="" method="post">
                    <div class="form-inner">
                        <h2 class="text-center">
                            <em>New Cumulative Deposit Account</em>
                        </h2>
                        <div id="cum_app_info">
                            <h3 class="text-center">
                                Personal Information
                            </h3>
                            <table class="table table-striped">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="first_app" class="control-label">First Applicant</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="first_app" id="first_app" required="" class="form-control" value=""/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="first_cum_app_id" class="control-label">Member Id</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="first_cum_app_id" id="first_cum_app_id" required="" class="form-control" value=""/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="second_app" class="control-label">Second Applicant</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="second_app" id="second_app" class="form-control" value=""/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <label for="second_cum_app_id" class="control-label">Member Id</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" name="second_cum_app_id" id="second_cum_app_id" class="form-control" value=""/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="4">
                                        <input type="submit" name="cum_app_next" class="btn btn-info" id="cum_app_next" value="Next"/>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank u dude... But the Bootstrap problem remains the same.

Comment: If that's not working for you i think it would mean that something else in your implementation is not right and it has nothing to do with the code you've shown in your question. Try to use one of the bootstrap templates first and get that working.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: Have you made any changes to the bootstrap css? Sometimes if you make changes to a stylesheet and put something incorrect in there, it can effect/break the rest of the stylesheet.